# How to add a child table while saving a parent table in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: lambda, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I need a help to add a child table while editing a parent table. i.e I need to insert a child table and update a parent table in a single controller method.

My usecase is while in both creating and editing a LabOrder(Parent table), a new set of consumedInventories(child table) to be added to the table.  In create method, it is working fine, i.e new set of consumedInventories get added, but in edit method, it causes error.

My Model:
// Parent Table

```
public class LabOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int LabOrderID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="The Order Date field is required."), DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Order Time field is required."), DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? OrderTime { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="The Hospital/ Clinic field is required.")]
    public int EntityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LabOrderStatusID { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Patient")]
    public int PatientID { get; set; } 
}
```

// Child Table

```
public class ConsumedInventory
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ConsumedInventoryID { get; set; }

    public int LabOrderID { get; set; }

    public int InventoryItemID { get; set; }

    public int ConsumedQuantity { get; set; }

    public int EntityID { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller code:

```
public ActionResult EditLabOrder(LabOrder lab)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConsumedInventory AddConsumedInventory = new ConsumedInventory();
        foreach (var stockItem in lab.ConsumedInventories.ToList())
        {
            AddConsumedInventory.ConsumedQuantity = stockItem.ConsumedQuantity;
            AddConsumedInventory.EntityID = stockItem.EntityID;
            AddConsumedInventory.InventoryItemID = stockItem.InventoryItemID;
            AddConsumedInventory.LabOrderID = stockItem.LabOrderID;
            db.ConsumedInventories.Add(AddConsumedInventory);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        db.Entry(lab).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I need to add one to five items in child table based upon the user input.

I am getting like this

> Attaching an entity of type 'ConsumedInventory' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

What am  I missing in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution..

Instead of adding a record one by one using foreach.. just use the EntityFramework 6's feature called **AddRange** to add record at Once...

This one worked fine for me

I have updated my controller code:

```
public ActionResult EditLabOrder(LabOrder lab){
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.ConsumedInventories.AddRange(lab.ConsumedInventories);
    db.Entry(lab).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
}
```